# Concrete Steps with Top Wooden Riser

Tags: concrete, wood, stairs, decking

I recently purchased a home and am working through some deferred maintenance issues. One issue is the front steps. There is a set of concrete stairs leading to a concrete landing and the issue is the final riser is wooden.

I removed the riser as it was pulling away from the landing and am trying to determine the best path to replace it.

[image: photo of the riser and siding]

The t100 siding on the side also was also waterlogged and rotten so will need to be replaced.

Any ideas on the best method to repair this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a stucco system of some sort? With wood swelling behind it, I wouldn't expect it to last long. I imagine that the stairs are solid concrete. I would be tempted to rip out the landing and redo that part with a blob of CMU block in its interior instead of the blob of wood.